# Find and replace accidental double quotes in quoted CSV using notepad++ and regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to fix accidental double quotes in a quoted CSV file using notepad++ (7.8.8) and regex

I want to find any double quote that doesn't have a comma before and after it, which I'm able to do.
But I don't want to match on quotes found in beginning of line or end of line, which I'm unable to do.

The following REGEX works on REGEXR but only if multiline flag is enabled, but notepad++ doesn't accept the /m for some reason.
`/(?<!^)(?<!,)"(?!,)(?!$)/gm`

[Sample on REGEXR](https://regexr.com/780pk)

Is there a way to enable the multiline flag in notepad++? If not, is there a way to re-write the expression to work without multiline support?

here's a simple test set with highlights on required matches:

[image: Sample]

Comment: I used notepad++ v8.4.9 and for me it seems to work, see https://imgur.com/a/bqzPQ7Y

Comment: maybe find/replace `([^,]+)"([^,]+)` with `\1\2`

Comment: @Thefourthbird you know you're right. I didn't test it on the sample I shared, I was only testing it on my real file. On the sample it works, on the real file it doesn't. The real file is somewhat large, and apparently the same expression won't work if the match is around 12M characters across around 16800 lines away from beginning of file.

Comment: Can you share a short part of the file? Does you current solution not work at all?

Comment: @JasonC There is no need for the two `+` quantifiers in your RexEx above. It makes little difference, but it could lead to slow performance in some cases.

Comment: @Thefourthbird the file itself doesn't matter. I replicated the issue by typing the letter A 10 times, then with copy pastes I replicated till I had 1000 of it per line, then replicated the line 12.5K times. That creates around 12.5M characters distance from the beginning of file till the first match, and that causes the expression to stop working.

Comment: Why would you create lines consisting of only `AAAAAAAAAA` ? You have a .csv file for which it does not work right? Can you create a regex101 demo with a part of the actual data? Perhaps try it like this `(?<=[^,\r\n])"(?=[^,\r\n])` https://regex101.com/r/2sxRQU/1

Comment: @AdrianHHH i had to think about your comment for a second but now it makes sense; yeah just `([^,])"([^,])` replaced with `\1\2` should give the same results; thanks